# log4j2 JsonTemplateLayout not working with maven shade plugin

Tags: log4j2, maven-shade-plugin

i am trying to generate logs in Json format for that using log4j2 JsonTemplateLayout with LogstashJsonEventLayoutV1.json as the template.  When i run the code using intellij everything works as expected.  But using java -jar command it fails with
Unable to locate plugin for type JsonTemplateLayout

Below are the logs from intellij and command line using java -jar

**Logs using java -jar command**
2021-04-20 19:02:55,123 main DEBUG null null initializing configuration org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfiguration@6f45df59

2021-04-20 19:02:55,140 main DEBUG Installed 1 script engine
Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
2021-04-20 19:02:55,723 main DEBUG Oracle Nashorn version: 11.0.10, language: ECMAScript, threading: Not Thread Safe, compile: true, names: [nashorn, Na
shorn, js, JS, JavaScript, javascript, ECMAScript, ecmascript], factory class: jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngineFactory
2021-04-20 19:02:55,723 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Core' found **122** plugins
2021-04-20 19:02:55,723 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Level' found 0 plugins
2021-04-20 19:02:55,739 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin type for JsonTemplateLayout

**Logs when executing from Intellij**
2021-04-20 18:52:50,289 main DEBUG Apache Log4j Core 2.14.1 initializing configuration org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfiguration@6ff29830
2021-04-20 18:52:50,306 main DEBUG Installed 1 script engine
Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
2021-04-20 18:52:51,122 main DEBUG Oracle Nashorn version: 11.0.10, language: ECMAScript, threading: Not Thread Safe, compile: true, names: [nashorn, Nashorn, js, JS, JavaScript, javascript, ECMAScript, ecmascript], factory class: jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngineFactory
2021-04-20 18:52:51,124 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Core' found **124** plugins
2021-04-20 18:52:51,124 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Level' found 0 plugins
2021-04-20 18:52:51,137 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=property, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Property].

Can anyone please help me resolve this issue?
Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

below link helped to resolve this issue

https://github.com/edwgiz/maven-shaded-log4j-transformer